# 100kHz active filter design

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, filter, signal-processing

I am designing a basic 100kHz active bandpass filter using opamps (LF353). I am only interested in receiving the 100kHz frequency (might drift a few kHz) from my input signal. I have used a basic Fliege bandpass filter, because it has low component count, simple, uses only 2 opamps and has adjustable frequency and Q control.

Parameters:

V(in) = 2v(p-p) sine wave 100kHz (for testing)

Bandwidth: 20kHz

f1 = 90kHz

f2 = 110kHz

Any suggestions for improvement or new designs? 

I have no restrictions except that I would like to use no more than 2 opamps, preferably LF353.

This is my design:
[image: Circuit diagram - Fliege filter - band pass]

And the Bode plot:
[image: Bode plot]

Comment: It seems to have the same number of components as a Sallen Key bandpass filter circuit would have (8). Both designs use only a single dual opamp package IC, which your LF353 will do. Check out some nice designs here: http://www.eng.yale.edu/ee-labs/morse/compo/sloa058.pdf

Comment: A "Twin-T filter" with active feedback can allow adjustments to Q, for potentially better selectivity than Sallen-Key 2nd order filter.

Comment: I have designed a Sallen Key filter (2 opamps) and the frequency response obtained seems a little poorer in comparison with the Fliege filter above. Also, the Fliege filter seems to be more adjustable in terms of frequency. However, I will look into that pdf document.

Comment: The "Twin-T filter" sounds interesting. But, I'm more keen on frequency adjustment as opposed to quality factor. Nonetheless, I will look into it.